# Same specificity, after taking placement into consideration, :first-letter always wins?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-specificity

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNddz/

```
.intro:first-letter {
    font-size: 130px;
}
span.letter {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
p {
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

The first rule consist of one class selector and one `pseudo-element` selector = 11

The second rule consist of one class selector `.letter` and one tag selector `span` = 11

Both rules have same specificity so it is reasonably to believe that the winner should be the last style. Obviously it is not the case. So I decided to add a `background-color` property to the second rule and as you can see it has a height of 30px.

I deduce from this that both rule are not selecting the same element. But it's kinda too bizarre that I want to have an official explanation to this effect.

Comment: Good question. This has no direct bearing on the effect described here but I thought I'd note that psuedo-elements use a double colon `::` in CSS3, rather than the single colon shared by psuedo elements and pseudoclasses in CSS2.

Comment: Seems like :first-letter is the winner on the font-size property of the letter... and the background-color is just acting on the span element that is set to 30px size.

Comment: It seems that specificity isn't the issue here because even if we make the rule with the **more specific** - the first-letter rule still wins http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZNddz/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I deduce from this that both rule are not selecting the same element.

This is because `.intro` is matching the `p` element whereas `span.letter` is a descendant of `.intro`. As already mentioned, specificity is not relevant when selectors are matching different elements. But since each selector *does* match some element, both rules are applied, resulting in your red background taking effect, on `span.letter`.

> But it's kinda too bizarre that I want to have an official explanation to this effect.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#application-in-css) contains some examples that are very similar to what you have: a block-level element that starts with an inline-level element that contains text, and styles applying to the block-level element, the `:first-letter` pseudo-element on the block-level element, and its inline-level child. In all of the examples, the `:first-letter` pseudo-element is always the innermost descendant in terms of formatting structure; this means that it's nested within the inline-level child element.

The last example illustrates with a hierarchy of elements including the pseudo-element, although the one just before that contains an overriding rule in its stylesheet, which demonstrates what happens in terms of the cascade:

> The following CSS will make a drop cap initial letter span about two lines:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
> <HTML>
>  <HEAD>
>   <TITLE>Drop cap initial letter</TITLE>
>   <STYLE type="text/css">
>    P              { font-size: 12pt; line-height: 1.2 }
>    P::first-letter { font-size: 200%; font-style: italic;
>                     font-weight: bold; float: left }
>    SPAN           { text-transform: uppercase }
>   </STYLE>
>  </HEAD>
>  <BODY>
>   <P><SPAN>The first</SPAN> few words of an article
>     in The Economist.</P>
>  </BODY>
> </HTML>
> ```
>
> This example might be formatted as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> The fictional tag sequence is:
>
> ```
> <P>
> <SPAN>
> <P::first-letter>
> T
> </P::first-letter>he first
> </SPAN> 
> few words of an article in the Economist.
> </P>
> ```
>
> Note that the `::first-letter` pseudo-element tags abut the content (i.e., the initial character), while the ::first-line pseudo-element start tag is inserted right after the start tag of the block element.

In your case, both `font-size` declarations apply as usual, but since `.intro:first-letter` is nested *within* `span.letter`, it uses its own `font-size` value. If you used a relative value [it would be calculated based on `span.letter`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/ZNddz/4), and if you didn't include a `font-size` style at all [it would simply inherit it from `span.letter`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/ZNddz/6).

Note that the `:first-letter` pseudo-element does *not* apply to inline-level elements (it does apply to inline blocks however):

> In CSS, the `::first-letter` pseudo-element applies to block-like containers such as block, list-item, table-cell, table-caption, and inline-block elements.

An inline box (one that is generated with `display: inline`) is not a [block container box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes). (An example of an inline-level box that *is* a block container box is an inline-block.)

If a browser is applying the pseudo-element to an inline, then it's in violation of the spec. While there's no indication of what should happen when you have a `:first-letter` rule for both a block container and an inline box descendant, since it does say that it does not apply to inlines, ideally a browser should always ignore the rule targeting the inline box descendant. Apparently, Chrome thinks otherwise; see [Danield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118036/css-same-specificity-after-taking-placement-into-consideration-first-letter/19118892#19118892).

Answer (score 2):

> I deduce from this that both rule are not selecting the same element.

Correct. You don't have to deduce this. Just open inspect element.

Given the following markup:

```
<p class="intro first"><span class="letter">L</span>sometext</p>
```

The following code sets the `:first-letter` pseudo element on the `<p>` tag:

```
.intro:first-letter {
    font-size: 130px;
}
```

The following code sets the `font-size` on the span element

```
span.letter {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

The code on the span **does not override** the code on the `<p>` - because they are targeting **different properties**.

Had I set the `first-letter` pseudo element on the span - then it would override the code on the `<p>`

[Here's a jsFiddle as proof](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZNddz/3/)

So you see there are no specificity issues here.

Comment: "The following code sets the `:first-letter` pseudo element on the `<p>` tag:" No, it does not. It does not apply the pseudo-element to anything, because `.letter` as a `span` is inline by default and that pseudo-element does not apply to inlines. That rule is being ignored entirely.

Comment: @BoltClock - I had a typo there. Thanks, i fixed that.

Comment: @BoltClock - take a look at the fiddle - the .letter:first-letter **does** override the  .intro:first-letter class

Comment: I was confused for a while, until I started opening other browsers. Chrome appears to be the only one where `.letter:first-letter` has any effect. That's... not right.