# CSS Precedence strange behaviour

Tags: css, operator-precedence

I was researching precedence in CSS and reading some articles, including this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html. According to him, attributes like classes have higher precedence over pseudo-elements. However, when I did a simple test, the opposite happened. Below, my code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li.item { font-size: 12px; }
ul li:first-letter { font-size: 20px; }
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k820L1kq/2/). Why the font-size of the first letter has 12 pixels instead of 20 pixels if the class has higher precedence than pseudo-elements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Selector precedence is the single hardest thing in CSS. Don't try to learn it =) Figure it out when there's a specific problem.

Comment: According to the article that I mentioned, I think that the precedence for the first selector would be 0,0,1,2 and the precedence to the second would be 0,0,0,3. Therefore, I expected that the rule of the first selector was applied...

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118036/same-specificity-after-taking-placement-into-consideration-first-letter-alway

Comment: @HashemQolami - Thanks, it helped, even being a bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just looked at your fiddle in Firefox, and you don't have a problem, it is working correctly. The font size of the word is 12px as asked for. But the first-letter pseudo element is all about identifying the first letter as a separate entitiy, and giving it a different style to that used for the rest of the word. As such, the specificity of the first letter is entirely separate from the specificity of the whole word; they do not override each other. 
So your first letter in the fiddle is correctly 20px.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. This happens because are different elements. The first letter is a different element of li. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I wasn't implying they are different element as such; they don't actually exist as elements; you won't find them in the DOM for instance. Which is why they are called pseudo-elements, and why I used the word entity not element! They are just a means to identify a part of an actual element, and tell the rendering engine to apply a different style to just that part.